# Как подставлять новое значение в переменную из строк файла через PHP?

Tags: php, парсер

Имеется файл 'sku.txt'. Каждая новая строка в нем содержит определенный артикул. Подскажите, как сделать подставлять по циклу в значение `$id`, которое равно одной строчке по порядку из файла 'sku.txt? В цикле должны исполняться последующие после надписи `// Loading page` команды.

```
$id = ;

// Loading page
$max_timout = 10;
$proxy = false;
$product_url = "https://www.ikea.com/ru/ru/catalog/products/$id";
$data = request($product_url, $max_timout, $proxy);

// Start parsing
$pq = phpQuery::newDocument($data['data']);

// Product title
$result['title'] = trim($pq->find('div.range-revamp-header-section__title--big')->html());
$result['title'] = preg_replace("/[a-zA-Z]/i", "", $result['title']);
```

Comment: обернуть всю вашу конструкцию после // в `foreach(file("sku.txt) as $id){ ...}` или что?

Comment: @teran это я понял, а как сделать так, чтобы значения для `id` забирались из текстового файла?

Comment: попробуйте прочитать первый комментарий еще раз, там этот id фигурирует

Answer (score 0):

считать строки файла и сделать по ним цикл

```
$lines = file("./sku.txt");
foreach($lines as  $id){
     .....  // ваш код
}
```